# Conversion failed because the DateTime data value overflowed the type specified for the DateTime value part in the consumer's buffer

Tags: oledb, sap-ase, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, sybase-ase15

i have a stored procedure in Sybase ASE with date params in it, so when i created a OLE DB Connection and passing the date parameters to the OLE DB Command,And we are mapping to the parameter with OLEDBType.DBTimeStamp type, datetime param type in stored procedure is smalldatetime. 
Here is the sample code.

```
OLEDBConnection  con = new OLEDBConnection(connectionstring);
con.open;

OLEDBCommand cmd = new OLEDBCommand(con);
cmd.QueryString = "dbo.job_xb_new"
cmd.QueryType = "Stored Procedure";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@signoff",OLEType.DBTimeStamp);
cmd.Parameters("@signoff").Value = Datetime.now;

cmd.executeNonQuery(); -----------> ERROR HERE
```

while executing the store-procedure i am receiving the error.
"Conversion failed because the DateTime data value overflowed the type specified for the DateTime value part in the consumer's buffer" ? 
Please help!!!

Comment: what's the actual value being passed to the database?

Answer (score 0):

With the only information given there may be a solution to try.

1. Change the datatype of your input value to the stored proc to a char/varchar

> ```
> create procedure dbo.myProc
> @inDate varchar(20)
> AS
> BEGIN
> ..
>
> END
> ```

2. Perform internal conversion from that with CONVERT before passing to your query.

> ```
> SET @inDate = CONVERT(datetime,@inDate,[style parameter number])
> ```

3. For troubleshooting, just comment out everything in the procedure and SELECT @inDate first to determine what the data coming in from the OLE DB app looks like. You may be in for a surprise there...